# Android webview display only <table> id of website

Tags: android, android-webview

I have

```
WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);  
                engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
                engine.loadUrl("http://www.fgcu.edu/search/directory-results.asp?V_LAST=" + inputName);
```

If you go to that url and look at the html source code, you will see that the results of the search all are with in the . I want to know if it is possible to not load everything out side of the table ID and just load the table.

Can i some how save the html code to a java list and search for the  id, and then delete everything else in the list? Not sure how i could do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the request using Apache's HTTPClient (included in Android's std. lib.), remove the parts you don't want and then loading it into the WebView using WebView.loadData()

Comment: Ya im just not sure how to remove the parts :/